# Как понять, что ты готов к фрилансу в области Android разработки?

Tags: java, android, фриланс

Я новичок, был на нескольких собеседованиях, пока что неудачно. 
В связи с самоизоляцией и переходом большинства предприятий на удалёнку, устроится джуном стало сложнее. В связи с этим мне интересно, насколько реально начать работать в качестве фрилансера, не имея производственного опыта и какие ещё могут быть пути решения проблемы трудоустройства и получения опыта в данной ситуации?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junior - это программист который знает, как решить поставленную задачу обучаясь за свой счет. 
Попробуйте сделать несколько приложений. Они будут полезны при приеме на работу. В принципе я могу помочь с направлениями.

Answer (score 2):

Читал где-то на эту тему и совет был такой: напиши приложение, которое будет полезно не только тебе. Т.е. подтекст такой, что если ты можешь увлечь своим продуктом, то ты будешь значительнее интереснее для компаний. Т.к. андроид-dev это больше маленькие компании, которые не могут позволить себе выращивать джунов, им нужно сразу на фронт отправлять бойцов, чтобы ты зарабатывал для компании.

PS Была идея, создать программку по изучению неправильных глаголов в англ.яз-е с проверкой знаний. По сути программка в реализации простая, но хэлп от неё существенный, т.к. англ для IT важная составляющая и многие начинают его подтягивать в процессе работы. А тут ты с такой софтинкой полезной :)